# Use logo of university in a presentation of work done elsewhere

Tags: etiquette, application

As a part of a PhD application process I have to give a talk about a project that I did a couple of years ago for an institution I no longer colaborate with.

I was thinking of putting the logo of my current institution in the first of my slides as a support when introducing myself and explaining my background to the people who are going to listen to my talk.

Is this considered a good practice? I have doubts because the work I am going to talk about has no relation whatsoever with my current university.

Comment: Your university may provide a [brand use](http://brand.jhu.edu/use-of-name/) guide. If it has nothing to do with your university, using it may be considered inappropriate use.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that the application process is about pitching YOU to the selection committee / other powers-that-be. Part of that pitch is introducing yourself -- and hence using your current uni logo would be appropriate. You should also explain that the work you're discussing was done elsewhere. That is, make sure anyone listening would not walk away with the wrong impression.

Answer (score 1):

When doing presentations that are joint with other institutions/individuals (or are supported by them), the other parties should be acknowledged, usually at the beginning and end of the talk. Presumably you are working on the presentation at your current institution, even if it is just fine-tuning the presentation and making other small changes. Because of this I don't think it's a problem to acknowledge your current institution and use their slide templates. But, I would recommend having the name and/or logo of all institutions that have contributed to the work in the slides.

Personally, I list collaborators and sponsors on the first slide and I acknowledge their contributions to the work being presented before I actually do the presentation. In your case I would say something like "I'm currently in position X at institution A; this is research done collaboratively with institution B along Y and Z who are at institutions A and B respectively." Putting this on the first slide allows everyone to see this before your start your talk. But, I usually try to put it again at the end as well. It is very hard to do research without other support, and so that support should be generously acknowledged.